# Applying a Function to Similarly Named Columns of Different Dataframes and Concatenating Result

Tags: python, pandas, function

Tried looking through previous questions and could not find one that matches my exact problem:

I have close to 300 Pandas dataframes named "df1" to "df300". They all have the following names and structure:

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4
0   3   8   4   9
1   3   5   3   6
2   4   7   7   3
3   10  1   10  6
4   4   4   7   9
5   6   4   1   3
6   10  8   6   3
7   7   1   1   10
8   7   6   9   8
9   10  3   4   6
```

To all the dataframes, I would like to apply this function:

```
def blend_data(dataframe):
   blend = (dataframe["X1"] + dataframe["X2"]) / (dataframe["X3"] * dataframe["X4"])
   return blend
```

And, concatenate the results in a new dataframe where the column "blend1" has the outputs from applying the function to "df1"; "blend2" has the outputs from applying the function to "df2" and so on. How would I do this?

Comment: can you load all 300 df into memory?

Comment: `pd.concat([blend_data(d) for d in list_of_your_dataframes],axis=1)`?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the dataframes `df1,df2,...,df300` first:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2, ... , df300], axis=0)
```

Followed by applying the `blend_data` function on `df_concat`:

```
df_blend = blend_data(df_concat)
```